# If $x_n \to +\infty$ then $(1+1/x_n)^{x_n} \to e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to prove that if $x_n$ is a numerical sequence such that $\lim_n x_n=+\infty$ then $\lim_n (1+1/x_n)^{x_n}=e$.

Should I pass by the continuous case (studying $f(x)=(1+1/x)^x$ for $x \to +\infty$) or can I prove it directly? Should i use $(1+1/n)^n \to e$ for $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

We have the sequential characterization of the limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\ell\iff \forall (x_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty\implies f(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\ell$$

Answer (score 0):

**Remark:** $$\lim_{x\to\infty } f(x)=\ell$$ if and only if for all sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=\infty $ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty }f(x_n)=\ell.$